# Show survey questions only in webpart of home page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, spfx-webparts, survey, survey-list

i want to show survey questions only to end users without default view of survey list in home page of sharepoint site .
and after user finished survey , it disabled  or want to handle error message of multiple responses of unique user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For disabling multiple responses, just go Settings of the survey -> Title, description and navigation and set  Allow multiple responses in survey options to Yes/NO. By default this options is NO.
[image]

For the requirement "show survey questions only to end users without default view of survey list in home page"

I assume you want to prevent users from viewing responses created by others. Go Survey settings>Advanced settings, enable the item-level permission.
[image]

Then the user can only see the response created by him/herself.Not be able to see a all items view.